# Adding JWT token into Facebook php SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, header, facebook-php-sdk, http-authentication

I want to create a rest-api with php and I have already implemented JWT tokens. At this time, I want to use Facebook API to log people into my system.

However, I'm getting the callback from Facebook without a JWT token so that I cannot know which user's Facebook access token it is.

```
First -> user registers into my system via their email.
Second -> user shall authenticate via facebook.
```

My JWT looks like this

```
{'email':'mehmetalisarac95@gmail.com'} -> this is my JWT token (decoded)
```

I want to know if I can pass headers in the request to Facebook URL.
If I cannot do this, how can I handle which user gets logged into my system via Facebook?

Comment: When a user _auths_ using Facebook, you should have access to the user's email. If this is not so,  you may need to setup your application to have particular scope to read user email. Use this email returned to create a JWT to pass around.

Comment: what if users email is not same with my database input ? @OluwafemiSule

Comment: AFAIK, the way to go is to create a new account. SO does that as well.

Comment: _“I want to know if I can pass headers in the request to Facebook URL.”_ - no, you can not do that in any URL. _“If I cannot do this, how can I handle which user gets logged into my system via Facebook?”_ - via the session?